# Stacked ActionBar Tab with Custom View Not Displaying Properly

Tags: android, android-actionbar

When using action bar tabs, sometimes they are displayed as "stacked" when tab content is too large for the display. A problem arises when I use a custom view for the tab content, it causes the selected tab to not be displayed in the dropdown, and once a tab is selected, the dropdown goes away, and small, empty tabs appear.

Here is a screenshot of the dropdown, before selecting an item: (note that the content of the tab is not displayed, even when the tab is selected)
[image: before selecting item]

Also, after selecting the item, the tabs are no longer stacked, and the content of the tabs is empty:
[image: after selecting item]

Here is my code, (note that I am using a custom view for the tabs just to demonstrate the problem)

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TextView selectedTabText = new TextView(this);
        setContentView(selectedTabText);

        ActionBar.TabListener listener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                TextView customView = (TextView) tab.getCustomView();
                selectedTabText.setText(customView.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            }
        };

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        addTab(actionBar, listener, "Tab one with a very long name");
        addTab(actionBar, listener, "Tab two with a very long name");
        addTab(actionBar, listener, "Tab three with a very long name");
        addTab(actionBar, listener, "Tab four with a very long name");
    }

    private void addTab(ActionBar actionBar, ActionBar.TabListener listener, String text) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(text);
        tab.setCustomView(textView);
        tab.setTabListener(listener);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug, and has already been reported to the bug tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41392

In order to work around this, I disabled the actionbar collapsing behavior with a nasty hack. The following method should be called from the onStart activity method:

```
/**
 * SUPER hack to disable tab collapsing with smaller screens, which doesn't allow custom tab bar views to be used
 * https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41392
 */
private void disableCollapsibleTabs() {
    try {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        Field actionViewField = actionBar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTabScrollView");
        actionViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mTabScrollView =  actionViewField.get(actionBar);

        Method setAllowCollapse = mTabScrollView.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setAllowCollapse", boolean.class);
        setAllowCollapse.setAccessible(true);
        setAllowCollapse.invoke(mTabScrollView, false);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", "Error while disabling actionbar collapsible tabs", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not work with android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Comment: Sorry but it doesnt work event using getSupportActionBar() insted of getActionBar(); I still not knowing what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ended up using

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/tint" />`
```

and not the deprecated Tabs of ActionBar.
This will not collapse the tabbar on orientation change but it seems apps of google and facebook do the same(i guess).

Update: Seems it didn't work, it was just a side effect.
It seems to be a timing problem -> when the code in onConfigurationChanged needs a bit time, the problem seems to be gone.
This really dirty hack finally worked but it is not a solution(and not recommended, perhaps a hint for somebody else to find it):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

---

For me this worked when called in my Fragment. Hope it helps.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reset your custom Tab when onConfigurationChanged method called.
It is worked for me.
Hope it helps.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
        actionBar.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(/*your custom view*/);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


}
```