# Title of the selected tab disappearing after screen orientation change

Tags: android, tabs, textview, screen-orientation

Im using android:configChanges to not recreate the activity on orientation change and all are working well except by one thing, the title of the selected tab disappear after the change, and i have no idea why. In order to set a warning for a specific tab, i made my tabs (actionbar.tab) get a custom view, maybe the problem is here.
I've made some tests with logcat and the text is still there on the textview.

```
 @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Log.e("irc", "Printing all the tab titles");

    for (int i = 0; i < actionBar.getTabCount(); i++) {
        ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.getTabAt(i);
        String texttab = ((TextView) tab.getCustomView().findViewById(
                R.id.tabtitle)).getText().toString();
        Log.e("irc", "Tab on " + i + ": " + texttab);
    }
// THE LOGCAT PRINTS ALL THE TAB TITLE, INCLUDING THE MISSING TITLE
}
```

Tried View.VISIBLE and setTextColor() on Textview too.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) actionBar.getSelectedTab()
            .getCustomView();

    TextView tv = (TextView) relative.findViewById(R.id.tabtitle);

    tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

//DOESNT WORK

}
```

The tab custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="64dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
android:layout_marginRight="-3dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tabtitle"
    style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity before change:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m7ntqk7h4g9vraq/2014-05-16%2003.33.09.png

Activity after change:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/iltbsfcgfraowri/2014-05-16%2003.33.16.png

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

My method on activity that add a tab on actionbar.

```
public void addPVTTab(String title) {
    MyService.log("Adicionando tab " + title + ".");
    Tab tab = actionBar
            .newTab()
            .setCustomView(createTabCustomView(title))
            // .setText(title) customview
            .setTabListener(
                    new MyTabListener<ChatFragment>(this, title,
                            ChatFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

}

private RelativeLayout createTabCustomView(String title) {

    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.tabtitle_layout, null);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabtitle)).setText(title);

    return view;

}
```

This can be called any time during the process, whenever another user send to me a new private message.

Comment: if you change your orientation back to potrait (after landscape and the title is gone) is the title come back or still missing?

Comment: Once it has gone, dont appears again. But i've just discovered that if i close the activity and re-open (my app is service based and state is recovered), it appears again. But again if i change orientation, disappear.

Comment: are you setting the title dynamically in oncreate?

Comment: Im posting the methods.

Comment: Happy to have developed the first application in the world not compatible with landscape orientation :)

Comment: try this for solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36424645/2002619 Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem, i was facing this error: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41392