# How to sinalize a tab (facing an android reported issue)

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, screen-orientation

I am developing an application that requires some of your tabs are flagged to indicate that there is new events to be viewed. So I'm using setCustomView () in tabs and changing the color of the title. To begin preparing the application to receive change of direction, I came across a bizarre problem in tabs. After a long search without answers i discovered that this is [a common android problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392818/stacked-actionbar-tab-with-custom-view-not-displaying-properly/) when mixing custom view in the tabs on landscape, and it seems mainly because by default ActionBar joins more than 3 tabs on a spinner in the ActionBar. I wonder if there is any solution to my problem because I've tried many things without success. I wanna can somehow sinalize that are something new in that tab. **Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that in my application, setting setNavigationMode(NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS) after adding all tabs, prevents the actionbar to collapse the tabs in a spinner, what cause this problem.
Now my tabs still displayed normally on actionbar even in landscape mode.
Hope it works for you.